# Assign query using 'match()' to subgraph

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I have a JanusGraph database with a graph structure as follows:

(Paper)<-[AuthorOf]-(Author)

I'm want to use Gremlin's match clause to query the data and assign the results to a subgraph. This is what I have so far:

```
g.V().match(
        __.as('a').has('Paper','paperTitle', 'The name of my paper'),
        __.as('a').in('AuthorOf').outV().as('b')).
select('b').values()
```

This query returns what I want, the Authors of the paper I'm for which I'm searching. However, I want to assign the results to a subgraph so I can export it using:

```
sg.io(IoCore.graphml()).writeGraph("/home/ubuntu/myresults.graphml")
```

Previously, I've achieved this with a different query structure like this:

```
sg = g.V().has('paperTitle', 'The name of my paper').
     inE('AuthorOf').subgraph('sg1').
     outV().
     cap('sg1').
     next()
```

Is there away to achieve the same results using the 'match()' statement?

Comment: Might I ask what makes you want to use `match()` in this case? your working query is quite concise already.

Comment: We're developing a web application with Janugraph as the backend and our middleware developer was having trouble constructing queries programmatically with the original syntax. We wanted to see if using the match syntax would make it easier.

Comment: always validate `match()` execution with `profile()` to be sure your graph, in this case JanusGraph, is compiling as you expect: http://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/04/18/snippet-8.html

Answer (score 0):

After a little trial and error I was able to create a working solution:

```
sg = g.V().match(
        __.as('a').has('Paper','paperTitle', 'ladle pouring guide'),
        __.as('a').inE('AuthorOf').subgraph('sg').outV().as('b')).
 cap('sg').next()
```

At first, I was trying to use the 'select' statement to isolate the subgraph. After reviewing the documentation on '[subgraph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step)' and learning more about side-effects in gremlin I realized it wasn't necessary.